# Using radio buttons to change input value from positive to negative

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to use radio buttons to convert an entered amount from positive to negative, however I am not accessing the value of the form attribute that i want to change.  I am new so let me try and explain my thinking.  I started out trying to convert the `:amount` attribute value within the create action, but no math was performed on the value which leads me to believe that I am not correctly accessing the attribute.  I then tried to create a method to filter the value through using `before_action` filter at the top of my controller obviously to no avail.  I guess my question is two part. 1) How do I correctly access the attribute from the form and 2) Would it be best to keep this logic in the controller or should I move it to the controller.  This is a simple app that adds or subtracts values and then updates the balance.  Any help would be welcome.

here is my form:

```
      <%= form_for(@deposit) do |f| %>

      <div><%= f.label :amount, class: "col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1" %></div>
      <div><%= f.number_field :amount, autofocus: true, class: "col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1" %></div>

      <div class="col-xs-1 col-xs-offset-2" ><%= f.radio_button(:cred_or_deb, true)%></div>
      <div><%= f.label :cred_or_deb, "Credit", class: "col-xs-3" %></div>

      <div  class="col-xs-1 col-xs-offset-1"><%= f.radio_button(:cred_or_deb, false) %></div>
      <div><%= f.label :cred_or_deb, "Debit", class: "col-xs-3"  %></div>

      <div><%= f.submit "Add", class: "btn btn-lg btn-dollars" %></div>

      <% end %>
```

here is my create action in my controller:

```
  def create
    @deposit = current_user.cash_records.build(cash_params)
    if @deposit.save
      @deposit.update_attribute(:balance, current_user.cash_records.sum(:amount))
      redirect_to user_path(current_user)
    else
      render 'cash_records/new'
    end
  end
```

and I thought it was best to use a before action to check for the arguments:

```
  def negate_amount
    if cash_params[:cred_or_deb] == false
      current_user.cash_records.build(cash_params[:amount]) * 2.0
    end
  end
```

my strong parameters are:

```
private 

    def cash_params
      params.require(:cash_record).permit(:amount, :cred_or_deb)
    end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my create action I updated the `:amount` attribute by calling the `.to_d` method on the form attribute and then chained the `to_s` and `to_i` methods onto the `:creed_or_deb` attribute so that i would only convert the `:amount` attribute if `:creed_or_deb` was false.

the create action looks like:

```
  def create
    @deposit = current_user.cash_records.build(cash_params)
    if @deposit.save 
      @deposit.update_attribute(:amount, -1 * cash_params[:amount].to_d ) if cash_params[:cred_or_deb].to_s.to_i == 0
      @deposit.update_attribute(:balance, current_user.cash_records.sum(:amount))
      redirect_to user_path(current_user) 
    else
      render 'cash_records/new'
    end
  end
```

It also seems to be fairly lean to leave this logic in the create action but any input would be welcome.